# Django rollback transaction after perform_create

Tags: django, postgresql, transactions

I am trying to use transaction.atomic with django without any luck I know I am doing something wrong but I dont know what.

```
class SnapshotView(BaseViewSet):
    serializer_class = SnapshotSerializer

    @transaction.atomic
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        # this will call serializer.save()
        snapshot = snapshot = super().perform_create(serializer)
        # this will run some code can raise an exception
        SnapshotServices.create_snapshot(snapshot=snapshot,
                                         data=serializer.initial_data)
```

the first method that creates a new snapshot will pass the second will raise but still I can see my snapshot instance in the db, why is that?
I am in transaction block and something fails, is django not suppose to do a rollback?

the second method will throw a custom exception
I read the doc and it seems that I am doing everything right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out. 
my problem was that django uses default DB when using in atomic is None. Because I am using different DB, I just added using to my decorator 
    transaction.atomic(using=MYDB) 
and that's fix my problem.